# How to restrict image size using frame while init in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having one init method where I am passing Image but I want to restrict its frame but I am not able to set it inside init as it's giving error.

```
public init(destinationImage: Image?) {
        self.destinationImage = Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down").resizable().scaledToFill() // error Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'some View'
    }
```

using it like

```
 ImageHeader(headerImage: destinationImage,
                                content: {
            Text(self.title)
                .Heading2(color: .white)
        })
```

Is there any way to restrict image size?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you want to restrict the frame? What you're doing in your init is giving the initialiser a `View` because you type-erase it with your view modifiers. Don't use the view modifiers in your init, use them in your view.

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't very compatible with how SwiftUI works  Views should always be a part of a `ViewBuilder` and not passed around/accessed like standard objects